# imsdroid for android and 3CX Phone sip for windows not connecting in asterisk over internet

Tags: asterisk, 3cx

I am running a local asterisk server in lan and can connect sip client from android and windows7. from android i made connection with imsdroid and for windows 3CX phone. Both working great.

Now i have just put my asterisk server in a server hosted from digitalocean. Tried to connect my sip clients but no luck.

I have noticed that no registration request coming in my asterisl CLI.

Local and Internet hosted both asterisk has same configuration. What changes I need to do?
I don't have any proxy server and I have checked the hosted asterisk port 5060 is in listening mode.

Answer (score 0):

When your server not in lan, you need set

```
nat=yes
```

in your sip peer settings.

For more info see http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+SIP+NAT+solutions

Comment: I have tested nat=yes but same result.

Comment: if so,check firewall on server (using iptables -L for example) and check your router setup(sorry, no way give instruction for any router, google for model name).

Comment: Hi I have tested iptables as you mentioned and found no ip is tehre. showuld i need to add the server ip? how?. command i executed with output: root@mhznode:~# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Comment: i have also checketd http://ping.eu/port-chk/the server ip and port :5060 but its saying the port is not open. but my asterisk service is running. What i need to do?

Comment: asterisk use UDP!!! port 5060 for sip. You should read more books about asteriks&linux, link above or hire someone if you not willing do so. There are no way give exact answer based on your info

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see if your Digital Ocean VPS has the IP Tables or some other firewall in place by default?

Comment: How can i check that in Digital Ocean VPS? Or how to check IP table or firewall?